# Google Product Forums - Post formatting icons grayed out?

Tags: google-product-forums

There doesn't seem to be a help forum for Google's Help Forum software.

I want to post a detailed question in the Google Drive help forum but all the formatting functions are grayed out for me, so my post ends up being displayed as a single unreadably long paragraph.

[image]

What's the magic incantation to enable the formatting icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about using Google Products Help forum could be posted in the forum where you are having questions about or issues.

Regarding the formatting options being grayed out that could happens due to the specific forum settings that limit those tools for new users.

The same happened to me recently on the Blogger forum in Spanish and just went to the Google Drive Help Forum and I'm facing the same, the editing tools are greyed-out.

Once you make more posts and get +1 and better answers you will gain higher levels and some restrictions will be removed.

Sidenotes:

1. The Help Center for Google Products Help Forum is https://support.google.com/groups
2. I'm a Top Contributor on several of the Google Product Help Forums from years, but now most of the time I'm using a "new" account.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems really stupid to prevent new users from using formatting though.

Comment: @JimGarrison I forgot to mention that I think that this was applied after the forums were spammed several times.